# Object to Void*

Tags: c, pointers

This might be a simple question, but I can't seem to get it right (not even with enough googling). Consider the following example:

```
Datum getDatum(...);
List* lappend(List *list, void *datum);

void my_fun(List **args){
   lappend(*args, getDatum(...));
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler yields an error because of a pointer mismatch for parameter 2 at `lappend` call within `my_fun`. I tried to put a `*`, like in `*(getDatum(...))` and an `&` but both didn't help, either.

What is wrong with that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that as return type of `getDatum` is `Datum`.

What you can do is,

```
void my_fun(List **args){
   Datum data = getDatum();
   lappend(*args, (void *)&data);
}
```

Comment: Ok! So it's basically not possible to put that in one line, right?

Comment: you can, but it's likely going to crash at runtime

Comment: But that code is more or less useless, since it will append the address of a local variable. That address becomes invalid as soon as `data` goes out of scope, i.e. when the function ends.

Comment: @unwind, that is different problem. OP had problem passing the parameter. None of us know how that parameter is used in `lappend`, so let OP make the choice to either change the function or keep it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert from a value like `Datum` to a pointer like `void*`, or `Datum*`. And you definitely cannot dereferenec a value type (what you tried with `*(getDatum(...))`)  If you change getDatum to

`Datum* getDatum(...);`

it should compile, but I suggest you read up on pointers etc. Also know that if you allocate Datum somewhere using malloc(), there should be a corresponding call to free(), which is going to get hard if you put everything in a void* list.